Ubuntu don't detect my battery
Ubuntu detect my battery only if i turn on pc while it's connected to charger.I have a samsung galaxy book4 ultra. I don't know what to do. I already tried to put acpi=force in grub configuration but it didn't work.

does it charge? if not you have a hardware problem. Ubuntu is not in charge of the battery. Your bios is. All Ubuntu does is ask the system info about the battery.

@Rinzwind yes it charges. idk what to do

I have the same issue. Lenovo hardware. Ubuntu 24.04
